# Google Chart error - won't display second graph

Tags: javascript, html, graph, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to integrate more than one chart in my page but only the first works.

The JS code is the following:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart_total);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart_fixed);

function drawChart_total() {
var fixed_costs = document.getElementById('total_fixed_costs').value;
var variable_costs = document.getElementById('total_variable_costs').value;
var salary = document.getElementById('total_salary').value;     

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string','Cost Type');
data.addColumn('number','Spendings');
data.addRows
([
   ['Fixed Costs', parseFloat(fixed_costs)],
   ['Variable Costs', parseFloat(variable_costs)],
   ['Salary', parseFloat(salary)]
]);
var options = {title: 'Total costs distribution chart', width: 600, height: 333};
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_total'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}

function drawChart_fixed() {
var truck_payment = document.getElementById('truck_payment').value;
var collision_comp_insurance =  document.getElementById('collision_comp_insurance').value;
var office_lease = document.getElementById('office_lease').value;   
var health_insurance = document.getElementById('health_insurance').value;   
var permits = document.getElementById('permits').value;

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Cost Type');
data.addColumn('number', 'Spendings');
data.addRows
([
   ['Truck Payment', parseFloat(truck_payment)],
   ['Collision / Comp Insurance', parseFloat(collision_comp_insurance)],
   ['Office Lease', parseFloat(office_lease)]
   ['Health Insurance', parseFloat(health_insurance)],
   ['Permits', parseFloat(permits)]
]);
var options = {title: 'Fixed costs distribution chart', width: 600, height: 333};
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_fixed'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

The data is taken from a form. 
The HTML tags for the form fields for the first graph are like this:

```
<input name="total_fixed_costs" id="total_fixed_costs" placeholder="Total" value=0 readonly>
```

and the ones for the second graph are like this:

```
<input type="number" min=0 id="permits" name="permits" placeholder="Write Here">
```

As far as the second graph goes, if I leave it as is, i ghet the following error:

*jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:36 Uncaught Error: Every row given must be either null or an array.*

On the other hand, if I do not use the parseFloat on the variables that populate the second column of the data table, i get the following error:

*jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:14 Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value  does not match type number in column index 1*

I've been searching for a solution to this for the last two days but without success. I want to mention that I am a newbie in the world of programming, currently learning JS. I did not yet have contact with JQuery.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first**, there is a typo...

*leave it as is*, meaning use `parseFloat`

AND

add a comma (`,`) at the end of this row...

`['Office Lease', parseFloat(office_lease)],  // <-- add comma`

**also**, it is *not* recommended to use `setOnLoadCallback` more than once

you can include the `callback` in the `load` statement,
then call the "draw" functions from there

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart_total();
    drawChart_fixed();
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart_total() {
  var fixed_costs = document.getElementById('total_fixed_costs').value;
  var variable_costs = document.getElementById('total_variable_costs').value;
  var salary = document.getElementById('total_salary').value;

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string','Cost Type');
  data.addColumn('number','Spendings');
  data.addRows
  ([
     ['Fixed Costs', parseFloat(fixed_costs)],
     ['Variable Costs', parseFloat(variable_costs)],
     ['Salary', parseFloat(salary)]
  ]);
  var options = {title: 'Total costs distribution chart', width: 600, height: 333};
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_total'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

function drawChart_fixed() {
  var truck_payment = document.getElementById('truck_payment').value;
  var collision_comp_insurance =  document.getElementById('collision_comp_insurance').value;
  var office_lease = document.getElementById('office_lease').value;
  var health_insurance = document.getElementById('health_insurance').value;
  var permits = document.getElementById('permits').value;

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Cost Type');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Spendings');
  data.addRows
  ([
     ['Truck Payment', parseFloat(truck_payment)],
     ['Collision / Comp Insurance', parseFloat(collision_comp_insurance)],
     ['Office Lease', parseFloat(office_lease)],
     ['Health Insurance', parseFloat(health_insurance)],
     ['Permits', parseFloat(permits)]
  ]);
  var options = {title: 'Fixed costs distribution chart', width: 600, height: 333};
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_fixed'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="number" id="total_fixed_costs" value="500" readonly />
  <input type="number" id="total_variable_costs" value="1500" readonly />
  <input type="number" id="total_salary" value="50000" readonly />
</div>
<div id="piechart_total"></div>

<div>
  <input type="number" id="truck_payment" value="400" />
  <input type="number" id="collision_comp_insurance" value="30" />
  <input type="number" id="office_lease" value="800" />
  <input type="number" id="health_insurance" value="100" />
  <input type="number" id="permits" value="20" />
</div>
<div id="piechart_fixed"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very very much!

That typo was the death of me. I looked over and over again but did not see it. I also modified the first part of the chart script, according to your instructions.

I had to change the HTML head to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

As per the instructions found on the Google Chart website (for displaying multiple charts on the same page), I initially had only the first row.

Now it works like a charm :)